# Две запятушонки

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые? Я думаю, ни одна не нужна.

`Я провожу занятия и онлайн(,) и офлайн. Во втором случае я выезжаю к Вам(,) либо Вы приходите ко мне на дом.`

Answer (score 1):

**Диалог 1**

— Вы проводите занятия онлайн или офлайн?

— ***И онлайн и офлайн.*** Во втором случае ***я*** выезжаю к Вам, либо ***Вы*** приходите ко мне на дом.

**Диалог 2**

— Вы проводите занятия офлайн или **только** онлайн?

— ***И онлайн, и офлайн***. Во втором случае ***я*** выезжаю к Вам, либо ***Вы*** приходите ко мне на дом.

**Пояснение**

1. Повторяющийся союз ***И...И*** используется в том случае, если у собеседника есть **сомнения** (только онлайн?).
2. Во втором предложении сопоставляются две ситуации, поэтому надо обе части выделить **ударением**.

Comment: Там союз И... И, а не ИЛИ... ИЛИ

Comment: Извините, исправила.

Comment: Но там же общая часть – *во втором случае*! Почему перед *либо* запятая?

Comment: А разве всегда второстепенный член объединяет два предложения в составе ССП? Исключений нет? К примеру, в данном случае нужно противопоставить две  ситуации, а не объединять их.  Да и союз ИЛИ у нас разделительный, а не соединительный. Зачем же соединять?